# NoReverseMatch 1 pattern(s) tried: ['PUTData/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

So I'm doing my first project using django showing examples of REST API methods like POST, GET, PUT, and DELETE through a made up database of first name, last name, and e-mail. I've been successful with POST and GET but now I am having trouble with PUT.

So I have three functions. First, a simple def function that shows all inputs of information so far. Second a class based function that lists the information in a specific order. And third, another class based function that shows the detail of that specific information. All functions work but now when I am linking the two html files together I am getting a error. I've tried a number of different ids when wanting to link to that specific information but they are just not working.

But here is my models.py:

```
class Information(models.Model):
    """Placeholder code that the viewer will be seeing."""
    info_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    e_mail = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return information."""
        return f"Info ID: {self.info_id}, First Name: {self.first_name}, Last Name: {self.last_name}, E-mail: {self.e_mail}"
```

Here is my forms.py:

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Information
        fields = ['info_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'e_mail']
        labels = {'first_name': 'First Name:', 'last_name': 'Last Name:', 'e_mail': 'E-mail:'}
        widgets = {'first_name': '',
                   'last_name': '',
                   'e_mail': '',
                   }
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
# Page(s) that shows the viewer an example of PUT.
    path('PUT/', InfoDataListView.as_view(), name='put_data'),
    path('PUT/<int:pk>/', InfoDataDetailView.as_view(), name='put_detail'),
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def put(request):
    put = Information.objects.all()
    context = {'put': put}
    return render(request, 'just_projects/put.html', context)

class InfoDataListView(ListView):
    model = Information
    template_name = 'just_projects/put.html'
    context_object_name = 'put'
    ordering = ['-date_added']

class InfoDataDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Information
```

Here are my two htmls: put.html and information_detail.html

```
{% extends "just_projects/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <p><h3>Information:</h3></p>

        <ul>
        {% for pt in put %}
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <h4 class="card-header">
                    {{ pt.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}
                    <small><a href="{% url 'just_projects:put_detail' PUT.id %}">Edit info.</a></small>
                </h4>
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ pt }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% empty %}
            <li>There is no information yet.</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    <hr />
{% endblock content %}
```

```
{% extends "just_projects/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p><h3>Information:</h3></p>
        <ul>
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <h4 class="card-header">
                    {{ object.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}
                </h4>
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ object }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    <hr />
    <p>
    </p>
{% endblock content %}
```

So the error message is a reversematch because they can't find the correct id right? The specific exception error and value is:
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'put_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['PUT/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

**EDIT**: Thank you Daniel Roseman!!!

Comment: i think error in this: `href="{% url 'just_projects:put_detail' PUTData.id %}`.  Your `PUTData.id` not correct. Can you show value of `PUTData.id`. If you want generate `href` for each element in `put_data` in html `{% for pd in put_data %}`. IT maybe is `pd.id`

Comment: I do not know what you mean by showing the value of PUTData.id? I've tried inputting the right integer and I get the correct result. For example, I have localhost:8000/PUTData/1 and it brings me to the first info set entered. Also I have tried pd.id.

Comment: `localhost:8000/PUTData/1` you have integer `1` is `PUTData.id`. You must have correct integer for reverse link. And maybe in your href `{% url 'just_projects:put_detail' PUTData.id %}`  your PUTData.id is something else like string. But try change it to `{% url 'just_projects:put_detail' pd.id %}` i think it can help you

Comment: I tried pd.id and it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Can you try interchanging the urls, so that one with the pk comes before the list view?

Comment: But wouldn't make more sense to have the list then when you click on that specific info that it would lead you to the detail?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong variable name within your `url` tag. Your object is called `pd`, so that is where the ID needs to come from.

```
<a href="{% url 'just_projects:put_detail' pd.id %}">
```

(Unrelated, but your `clean` method is pointless; it is within the Meta class so it will never actually be called, but also it does nothing useful. You should delete it.)

**Edit** looking at your models, your primary key is called `info_id` for some reason. So either do `pd.info_id`, or just `pd.pk`.

Although I would question why you need to change the name of the primary key in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the clean method, I will delete it.  But I already tried the pd.id. I've tried put.id, I've tried putdata.id, I've tried info.id, and pk.id. Shouldn't the variable name id be related to the html tag it's connected to? So like since my information_detail is the one we're trying to link to shouldn't I use the variable id related to that file?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying at all. You're doing `{% for pt in put %}`, therefore the item with the data you need to construct the URL is `pt`. Therefore you need to do `{% url 'just_projects:put_detail' pt.id %}` (I note that you've edited the question since I posted my answer, so now you have `pt` rather than `pd`.)

Comment: Yeah, sorry editing it because I was trying different stuff. And yes I already tried pt.id and pd.id and it still does not work.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much!!!! I was so frustrated. But thank you, I understand your answer.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, as a sign to future searchers that it solved your problem.